# Send dm to a user who has pressed the button

Tags: python, discord.py

How to send dm to a user who has pressed the button in discord?

```
await ctx.send(
        embed = emb,
        components=[
            Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="Buy!")
        ]
    )

    response = await Bot.wait_for("button_click")
    if response.channel == ctx.channel:
```

Answer (score 1):

Well first you need to get the user who pressed that button not sure if this works but maybe `user = response.author` and then you can send dm like this `await user.send(your_text_here_must_send_as_string)`
. If `response.author` wont work you must get the id of the user and then fetch it like this `user = Bot.fetch_user(id_of_user_as_int)`